# Producing an RDD with the sum of each word's occurrence in each line of a text with Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Given an RDD from a text file with N lines such as the following:

```
['word1, word2, word3, word1, word3, word4, word3',
'word1, word5, word5, word5', word1, word4]
```

I'm trying to produce an RDD which will count the word frequencies in each line, with the pattern: `(line_no, (word, frequency_of_word_in_line))`, for example:

```
(1, (word3, 3))
(1, (word1, 2))
(1, (word2, 1))
(1, (word4, 1))
(2, (word5, 3))
(2, (word1, 2))
(2, (word4, 1))
```

I'm able to count the word occurences throughout the text, i.e. with `RDD.flatMap(lambda x: Counter(x.split(' ')).items()).reduceByKey(add)` and split the text by lines with `RDD.zipWithIndex().map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))`, but I'm at a loss at how to combine them to get the result I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done with dataframes

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as sf
sparkSession = SparkSession(sparkContext)

# create the data example:
words = ['word1, word2, word3, word1, word3, word4, word3',
         'word1, word5, word5, word5', 
         'word1','word1, word3', 
         'word4, word2, word2']

rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(words)  # create the rdd of the words
rdd2 = rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))  # add the line number

# now let's count some words:
df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rdd2, schema="line_num: int, line: string")  # convert the rdd to a dataframe
df2 = df.withColumn("words", sf.split(df.line,",\s+"))\   # split the line to words 
        .withColumn("word", sf.explode("words"))\  # explode the words so that each has it's own row
        .groupby('line_num','word')\  # group by rows with the same row_num and word
        .count()  # and count them

# now go back to your requested representation of rdd of tuples
rdd3 = df2.rdd.map(lambda row: (row['line_num'], (row['word'],row['count'])))
```

Comment: Hi - thanks a lot for the reply! Why `sparkContext.parallelize(words)` and not `sparkContext.textFile('myfile.txt')`? I create the initial RDD from a text file...